# JProperty Converting to String instead of Array of Objects

Tags: c#, json.net

I want to add a custom parameter to an already parsed Json object. The custom parameter is composed of more than one value, thus an array of objects in the Json format is desired.

When it is added to the `jsonObj` it is treated as a whole string instead of an array.

```
var objs    = new List<JObject>();
var jsonObj = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myTable, jsonSettings));

// Add Custom Parameter
jsonObj.Add(new JProperty("myArray", "[\"" + myTable.Col1 + "\", \"" + myTable.Col2 + "\"]"));

objs.Add(jsonObj);
```

Current output:

```
myArray:"[\"Col1Val\", \"Col2Val\"]"
```

Desired output:

```
myArray:[\"Col1Val\", \"Col2Val\"]
```

Comment: I don't understand what the difference between current and desired output is. It looks like all you want is to remove the double quotation marks?

Comment: When adding the custom parameter I do not have an extra quotation mark, but by using 'new JProperty ("myArray"', ...' it adds the quotation mark and treating the parameter as a string. What do I need to change so it does not add the extra quotation mark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it work you should use the correct [constructor](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty__ctor_2.htm)

```
public JProperty(
    string name,
    params Object[] content
)
```

So you should write this if you need to store an array content:

```
jsonObj.Add(new JProperty("myArray", myTable.Col1, myTable.Col2));
```